# How can I recognize the guest user after they signup?

Tags: javascript, unique-key

Is there anyway I can assign uniqueId to the guestUser when they landup on my website and then once they signup I can recognize that User with the uniqueId?

Comment: You can set a cookie when the guest user arrives, then check the cookie when they login. More: https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_cookies.asp

Answer (score 2):

You can always store data in local storage.For your case let's just store a uniqueID in local storage.Next time if he signups from same browser you can read that Id and recognize that user.
To store some unique id in local storage you can run

```
localStorage.setItem("unqiueId", "someRandomID");
```

inside script tag.
To retrive that Id you can use

```
let uniqueID = localStorage.getItem("unqiueId");
```

Comment: Thanks Maaz Afzaal, But how to do it? Any code reference please?

Comment: Also I checked under the Network tab I was getting some unique id whenever I am visiting the same website , it is showing the same unique id even if I refresh. But the problem is I don't know how to get  that query String parameters in JS?

Comment: I have edited the answer.Further it would be better if you can share the screenshot of that ID you are getting under network tab.